# Glimpse lost account of time? Slow web form requests

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms, glimpse

I just installed glimpse to try and track down some slow loading on pages that basically don't do much. This issue happens on local(not as bad though) but worse on pre production server.

I see the start request, then nothing.. then all the SQL and page cycles (yes, still damn web forms) all go quickly ~800ms. For an empty site that is is pretty shite but the problem is it takes 2,3 sometimes 6 seconds and I cannot work out why.

Anybody know how to work out the missing piece?

[image]

[image]

On the lifecycle it looks like its already delayed `1916.02ms` What comes before the lifecycle of webforms?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can look into:

1. Is this only happening on the first hit to the page? (IE: Is this JIT overhead?)
2. Do you have any HTTP Modules doing work during `BeginRequest`?
3. What about `Global.asax` and `BeginRequest`?

You can add `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write()` statements in your `BeginRequest` and look at the Trace tab and Timeline tabs to get more information about the time in the red box.

Comment: Yea possibly HTTP Modules. This project uses Castle Windsor but I cant find a plugin for glimpse, only autofac. So it could be that doing something long winded. It happens even after first page load and seems to be random. Cant work out what it is. Thanks for the tips - I got a new angle to check out.

Comment: I put a trace and BeginRequest and its shows up 'My Trace - 0ms' then 'Preinit 5000ms' - SO I am not sure how to catch what is going on in the request lifecycle if there is such a thing.